# routing from container to a VM on a laptop

Tags: ip, routing

I have a docker daemon running on my laptop and have started a container. The IP of the container is 172.17.0.2/16.

I also have a VM running and its IP is 172.20.8.102/16.

I want to be able to ping the VM from the container. When I try, ping just hangs.

Should I add something to the route table of the container or laptop?

The route table the container looks like this:

```
root@3ab67fd10821:/# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2
```

The route table of the laptop looks like this:

```
[~/proj] ip route
default via 10.0.1.1 dev en0
10.0.1.0/24 dev en0  scope link
10.0.1.1/32 dev en0  scope link
10.0.1.3/32 dev en0  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo0
169.254.0.0/16 dev en0  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev en3  scope link
169.254.48.158/32 dev en3  scope link
172.17.8.0/24 dev vboxnet  scope link
172.18.8.0/24 dev vboxnet  scope link
172.20.8.0/24 dev vboxnet  scope link
192.168.65.0/24 dev vboxnet  scope link
224.0.0.0/4 dev en0  scope link
224.0.0.0/4 dev en3  scope link
255.255.255.255/32 dev en0  scope link
255.255.255.255/32 dev en3  scope link
```

The route table of the VM looks like this:

```
[core] ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 1024 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 
10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 1024 
172.20.0.0/16 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.8.102
```

Comment: Host should have capability of forwarding since all traffic going via host machine

Comment: Thanks Alex, I do indeed see that the host can ping the desired VM. But it doesn't work from the container. Perhaps its a firewall issue? Do you know where I might look for that on a mac?

Comment: Try : `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`